# How could an "also if" be implemented in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, series

I want to implement something conceptually like the following:

```
if condition1:
    action1()
also if condition2:
    action2()
also if condition3:
    action3()
also if condition4:
    action4()
also if condition5:
    action5()
also if condition6:
    action6()
else:
    print("None of the conditions was met.")
```

What would be a reasonable and clear way of implementing logic like this? How could an `else` be bound to multiple `if` statements? Would I be forced to create a boolean to keep track of things?

Comment: How is this different from `elif`?

Comment: Just remove the invalid `also`.  If the conditions are not dependent, just check each one with `if ..:`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c but he needs an `else` to encompass `if not any(condition)`

Comment: @AdamSmith - so `if not any(conditions):`?

Comment: By "also" do you mean that, for example, `condition2` is only checked if `condition1` is true?

Comment: Do you want ```action2``` to be completed if _only_ ```condition2``` is true?  Or do you want ```action2``` to be completed if ```condition1``` and ```condition2``` are both met?

Comment: I want ```action2()``` to be completed if only ```condition2``` is True. Then, whether ```condition2``` is True or False, I want ```action3()``` to be completed if only ```condition3``` is true and so on. If none of the conditions are True, I want the statement printed.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, based on the clarification, something like this would work well:

```
class Accumulator(object):
    none = None
    def also(self, condition):
        self.none = not condition and (self.none is None or self.none)
        return condition

acc = Accumulator()
also = acc.also

if also(condition1):
    action1()
if also(condition2):
    action2()
if also(condition3):
    action3()
if also(condition4):
    action4()
if acc.none:
    print "none passed"
```

You can extend this to get other information about the execution of your if statements:

```
class Accumulator(object):
    all = True
    any = False
    none = None
    total = 0
    passed = 0
    failed = 0

    def also(self, condition):
        self.all = self.all and condition
        self.any = self.any or condition
        self.none = not condition and (self.none is None or self.none)
        self.total += 1
        self.passed += 1 if condition else self.failed += 1 
        return condition
```

Comment: This is cute! I like it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this. The [any approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494596/how-could-an-also-if-be-implemented-in-python/24494639#24494639) described by @jonrsharpe is very good, but requires the conditions to be specified twice. Your approach allows for a single specification of the conditions and is written such that an English-like syntax may be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest:

```
if condition1:
    action1()
if condition2:
    action2()
...
if not any(condition1, condition2, ...):
    print(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this. I had not known about the ```any``` function and, conceptually, it is what I was looking for. It does require the conditions all to be specified twice, though, which is why I think [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24495556/1556092) provided by @Jamie Cockburn (in which a boolean is used to keep track and conditions are specified only once) makes more sense. I thank you most sincerely for your help!

Answer (score 6):

```
conditionMet = False
if condition1:
    action1()
    conditionMet = True
if condition2:
    action2()
    conditionMet = True
if condition3:
    action3()
    conditionMet = True
if condition4:
    action4()
    conditionMet = True
if condition5:
    action5()
    conditionMet = True
if condition6:
    action6()
    conditionMet = True

if not conditionMet:
    print("None of the conditions was met.")
```

Comment: your last line is mixing languages. You mean `if not conditionMet`

Comment: `conditions = {condition1: action1, condition2: action2, ... }; for condition, action in conditions.items(): if condition: action(); conditionMet = True`

Comment: @AdamSmith that is the cleanest scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. @Jamie Cockburn [uses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24495556/1556092) what is, in essence, your approach, but builds on it by allowing for English-like syntax when using the approach of keeping track using a boolean. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
conditions = [condition1,condition2,condition3,condition4,condition5,condition6]
actions = [action1, action2, action3, action4, action5, action6]

for condition, action in zip(conditions, actions):
    if condition:
        action()

if not any(conditions):
    print("None of the contitions was met")
```